# Unable to import CSS Stylesheet

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm building a Reacs.js website, and I've been trying to import a .CSS file to my main App.js, but I always get the same error.

I import my CSS file:

> import './Assets/Css/default.min.css'

And I get the following error:

> ./src/Assets/Css/default.min.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/Assets/Css/default.min.css)
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

How can I solve his problem?

Comment: are you trying to import default.min.css(minified css file) or default.css?

Comment: The minified one